# Disabling call to function for 5 seconds after triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that I want to disable from sending anymore calls to jquery while there is a function "active".

What happens is, every-time a user clicks on the button, the counter gets reduced by 1.
However this happens with a delay, see here the steps;

- click button
- Button gets disabled
- 5 seconds later counter gets reduced with one and button changes to enabled.

However, the problem right now is that, even while the button is supposed to be disabled, users can just click is X amount of times, and the counter gets reduced with that X amount of times after 5 seconds.

Meaning the calls still go through.

See here what I tried to do so far, but unfortunately with no success..

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var enabled=true;

    $(".myButton").click(function(){

        if(enabled = true) {

        setTimeout(function(){
            var i = document.getElementById('counter2');
            i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;
            $('.progress-bar').css("width", '+=' + '35px');
            $(".myButton").attr('disabled','enabled');
            $('.myButton').css('opacity', '1');
            var enabled=true;
        },5000)
        $(".myButton").attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('.myButton').css('opacity', '0.5');
        var enabled=false;

        } else { }

    });
});
```

Comment: i think you're really close, try removing `var` from all but the first declaration on line 2, you are defining new variables with the same name in the new function scopes (`click` and `setTimeout` callbacks)

Comment: Just tried that, but no success :( It continues to do the same (adding up the clicks and reducing the countdown by all of them)

Comment: if enabled = true ? ... Just saying... before continue reading

Comment: @Tsalikidis I do not understand what you are saying

Comment: if (variable = true) is always true in javascript. (I think at least...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(enabled = true) {
           ^
```

You meant to write `==` here. Or even better: `if (enabled)` as `enabled` is a boolean anyway.

Using `= true` is an assignment here as well. And as `true` is truthy the condition will always evaluate to `true`.

Comment: yep this was the problem along with a missing semi colon after the timeout.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to track a variable to monitor the state of the button, because you already set an attribute to indicated that it's disabled. So you can just use that attribute as an indicator of it's state.

Also, you are doing this behavior on *all* buttons of class `myButton`. So I isolated the handler to just `event.target` which was the button that was clicked.

```
$(".myButton")
    .prop('disabled',false)
    .click(function(event){
       // get the button that was clicked.
       var btn = $(event.target);
       if(btn.prop('disabled') === true) {
             // it's already disabled, nothing to do
             return;
       }

       // start a 5 second timer
       setTimeout(function(){
           var i = document.getElementById('counter2');
           i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;
           //$('.progress-bar').css("width", '+=' + '35px');
           // I've never seen += used like this ^^^ does it work?
           var bar = $('.progress-bar');
           bar.css("width", (bar.width() + 35) + 'px');

           // after 5 seconds enable the button
           btn.prop('disabled',false);
           btn.css('opacity', '1');
        },5000);

        // disable the button until timer expires.
        btn.prop('disabled',true);
        btn.css('opacity', '0.5');
    });
```